# How to replace the cell text of a table with currently selected cell text in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table with some values. I am getting the current selected value from a jQuery click event as shown below.

When I click `1` I get `1` in console. When I click `2` I get `1` and `2` both.

When I write `$(selectedValue).remove()` it doesn't work. Also it doesn't work if I write `$(selectedValue).text()`

I just want the value `2` in console i.e. I want to replace the old value with a newly clicked (or selected) value.

```js
$('td').click(function() {
  var selectedValue = $(this).text(); // get the current cell text
  $(selectedValue).remove(); //this doesn't reset the value
  var row = $(this).parent().text();
  console.log(selectedValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>First</th>
    <th>Second</th>
    <th>Third</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `selectedValue` will be a number, not a valid jQuery selector, so putting it in to a jQuery object won't have the effect you're looking for. Can you explain more about your intended goal. I don't understand where the new value is supposed to come from when you click a `td`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan see the table. Let's say I click '1' so console will show me '1', then when I click '2' I want the console  to show only '2', but it shows '1' and '2' both values.

Comment: I placed your code in a snippet where it already works as you describe - at least the logging the value to the console does. `$(selectedValue).remove();` is wrong and will never work

Comment: @noobprogrammer so you want to clear the console before shwoing the new value right ? because everything works fine

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I think he wants to clear the console before showing the new value

Answer (score 1):

nothing wrong with your code, and the values are printed correctly in console, what you are trying to achieve is clear the console before printing the newly selected value, one way to get the result you want is :

- the best solution is to creat a label inside your html and print the value of the selected cell inside the label instead of the consol
- manually clear the console after each value selection
- programmatacclly print new empty lines to simulate the clearing befor every selection like this :

  ```
  $('td').click(function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).text(); // get the current cell text
    var row = $(this).parent().text();
    console.log('\n'.repeat('25'));
    console.log(selectedValue);
  });
  ```
- another way is to use a console.clear() function but that's a bit tricky since it changes from a browser to another :

  ```
   $('td').click(function() {
      var selectedValue = $(this).text();
      var row = $(this).parent().text();
      // For Chrome
      if (typeof console._commandLineAPI !== 'undefined') {
      console.API = console._commandLineAPI;
      } 
     // for Safari
     else if (typeof console._inspectorCommandLineAPI !== 'undefined') {
     console.API = console._inspectorCommandLineAPI;
     } 
    else if (typeof console.clear !== 'undefined') {
     console.API = console;
     }
     console.API.clear();
     console.log(selectedValue);
   });
  ```